# Automate a pipenv update run before merging

Tags: python, pipenv

My team has decided they want to enforce installing the latest version of packages before merging to master so that they don't become too out of date.  So someone set up a pre-commit hook to call `pipenv update` to update the lock file and then install new versions of dependencies.

However, this has caused a major slow down in my development cycle.  The update command can take almost 5 minutes to run each time I commit, and if it actually updates anything the hook fails and must run again for another 5 minutes.

Is there a best practice for keeping the lock file up-to-date? If this is it, can it be sped up?